# How can I change color of each option in combo box?

Tags: python, pyqt5

How can I change color of each option in combo box in pyqt5? I want to yellow color, green, blue, etc.

[image]

This is my code.

```
self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
self.combo_box.setGeometry(200, 150, 150, 30)
geek_list = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"]
self.combo_box.addItems(geek_list)
self.combo_box.setStyleSheet("QListView"
                             "{"
                             "background-color: red;"
                             "}")
```

`

Can you also tell me how to send value of this options to first window? For example if I choose red color how can I print number 1 in my first window

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QBrush
import sys

class AnotherWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setWindowTitle("Zmiana tła")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(700, 700, 500, 500)

        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)

        self.combo_box.setGeometry(10, 10, 150, 30)

        geek_list = ["Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"]

        self.combo_box.addItems(geek_list)

        self.combo_box.setStyleSheet("QListView"
                                     "{"
                                     "background-color: red;"
                                     "}")

        self.combo_box.activated.connect(self.do_something)

    def do_something(self):
        value = self.combo_box.currentIndex()
        return value


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 360, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialogi")
        self.w = AnotherWindow()
        # create menu
        menubar = QMenuBar()
        layout.addWidget(menubar, 0, 0)
        actionFile = menubar.addMenu("Dialog")
        action = actionFile.addAction("New")
        action.triggered.connect(self.w.show)
        actionFile.addAction("Open")
        value_from_window_two = self.w.do_something()
        print(value_from_window_two)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QComboBox uses an internal [QStandardItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) (unless another model is explicitly set) which allows setting some properties for each item ("index") of the model.

Qt models provide some predefined [*roles*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) which are data fields specific to each index, and among those roles there is the `BackgroundRole`.

You can then use [`setData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#setData) for that role specifying the index and the value.

In the following example I'm using the string constructor of QColor which uses the standard SVG colors. Also note that:

- if you want the current index selected from the user, you cannot get it when the widget is created (as you're trying to do at the end of the `__init__` of `Window`);
- you should use layouts more properly, for instance, you're not adding the combobox to the layout of `AnotherWindow`;
- related to the above point, trying to set fixed geometries is usually discouraged, as you cannot know the screen layout and OS features on the target system; for instance, I have two screens, with the right one as the main one, and having windows that automatically are created on the left one is quite annoying;
- if you want a menu bar, you should use a QMainWindow and call [`menuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#menuBar) instead; if you *really* need a basic QWidget, you should add the menubar using the dedicated layout function [`setMenuBar()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setMenuBar);
- for this kind of situations, using a QDialog is preferred instead of a QWidget, as it allows using *window modality* and also provides the `exec_()` blocking function that ensures you can get the result as soon as the dialog is closed (accepted or rejected);

```
class AnotherWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel()
        self.setWindowTitle("Zmiana tła")
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.combo_box = QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.combo_box)

        geek_list = ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"]

        model = self.combo_box.model()
        for row, color in enumerate(geek_list):
            self.combo_box.addItem(color.title())
            model.setData(model.index(row, 0), QtGui.QColor(color), QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)

        self.combo_box.activated.connect(self.accept)

    def color(self):
        return self.combo_box.currentData(QtCore.Qt.BackgroundRole)

    def colorName(self):
        return self.combo_box.currentText()


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialogi")
        actionFile = self.menuBar().addMenu("Dialog")
        action = actionFile.addAction("New")
        action.triggered.connect(self.selectColor)
        actionFile.addAction("Open")

    def selectColor(self):
        dialog = AnotherWindow(self)
        if dialog.exec_():
            print(dialog.color())
            print(dialog.colorName())
```

Comment: Thank you very much :D

Comment: Could you help me with another question beacuse i really dont know what could be wrong? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67406561/what-is-wrong-in-my-pyqt-program-that-it-is-closing-after-moving-the-slider?noredirect=1#comment119144664_67406561